# powerquery - filter a column which contains tables with errors

Tags: filter, powerquery

I have a query which creates dynamic sql query. But the sql code returns errors in some rows. I tried to add an additional column to filter the column with no errors but didnt work.

```
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "fnButunSantiyeler", each fnButunSantiyeler([Query])),
Step2 = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Custom", each if Value.Is([fnButunSantiyeler], type table) then [fnButunSantiyeler] else #table({"ConvertedText"}, {{[fnButunSantiyeler]}})),),
```

[image]

any ideas to get rid of the error rows ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cant filter to remove error, then perhaps convert the errors to a null then remove rows with a null

Does this work for you?

```
x = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepName", {{"fnButunSantiyeler", each try if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else null otherwise null }} )
```

then use arrows atop the column to filter out null

Comment: thanks for the effort but didnt work...

Comment: what is the result of trying?

Comment: no result, nothing changed and still showing expand icon instead of standard arrow so i couldnt filter the column....

Comment: **Step2 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function", {{"fnButunSantiyeler", each try if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else null otherwise null }} ),**

Comment: actullay i get this error on the next step, it may give an idea... **Expression.Error: This native database query isn't currently supported.** the query returns zero result that's why this error occurs...

Comment: How many rows do you have? Can you try to trim down to like 10 rows before that step using = Table.FirstN(#"Invoked Custom Function",10) first just to see if the method works?

Comment: Does it work if you do it as a new column ?   if Value.Is([fnButunSantiyeler],, type table) then [fnButunSantiyeler]  else null otherwise null

Comment: only 1061 rows... it does not change any error to null...

Comment: as you see in my question, i've already tried this method...

Comment: what happens if you simply right click the column and replace errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243900/discussion-between-umut-k-and-horseyride).

Answer (score 0):

you can't `Value.Is` an error

instead, do this

```
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "fnButunSantiyeler", each try fnButunSantiyeler([Query]) otherwise "query failed"),
```

M-language provides a robust error handling methodology, you can read them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-error-handling).

Comment: didnt work ... **Expression.Error: This native database query isn't currently supported.**